# RequiredAttribute and JsonSerializationException in WebApi2

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

According to [Model Validation in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api), RequiredAttribute should have no effect on a missing non-nullable parameter during model validation.

> "Under-posting":
>
> Here, the client did not specify values for Price or Weight. The JSON
>   formatter assigns a default value of zero to the missing properties.
>
> The model state is valid, because zero is a valid value for these
>   properties.

I'm updating a piece of code that has [Required] marked on a property like so:

```
public class Thing
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

and the controller method:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PutThing(Thing thing)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (thing.Id == 0) // Create
        {}
        else // Update
        {}
    }
    else
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
    }
}
```

If I debug the controller code, I can see the "thing.id" is set to 0, but ModelState.IsValid is false, with the following error:

```
400 BadRequest - Thing.PutThing - {\"thing\":{\"Errors\":[{\"Exception\":{\"ClassName\":\"
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException\",\"Message\":\"Required property 'Id' not found in JSON. Path '', line 1, position 332
```

Am I missing something about how this works?

It seems like this is an improper use of the [Required] attribute based on the way the controller method is using the "id" property anyway, but I'd just like to know why I'm getting a different behavior than what the docs say.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that, if I don't check ModelState.IsValid, the above code works fine, and sees that thing.Id is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Required] means you are forcing the client to send that value. In your case the Web api converts your json and initializes Thing.Id to 0 but it wasn't sent by the client so the model is invalid. If you do not want to force the client to sent the value of Id remove [required] on top of Id in the model. Another thing you can do is sending 0 from the client when you want to create and a different value when you want to update. 
I don't know why you are coupling those two actions, but according to me you should have separate actions for creating and for updating.